# VueJS & Firebase - How to validate someone's password

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I have a web form built with VueJS that allows authenticated users to change their passwords. The backend is using Firebase, and I'm trying to validate the user's current password prior to calling the password-change API.

My code looks like this:

```
rules: {
    ...
    isPreviousPassword: v => {
      var credentials = await firebase.auth().currentUser
        .reauthenticateWithCredential(
            firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(
            firebase.auth().currentUser.email, 
            v)
        )

      return credentials || 'Your password is incorrect'
    }
}
```

Babel refuses the code above and returns the following error:

```
Syntax Error: await is a reserved word
```

I haven't found any ways to get over this error, and none of the code snippets I found online, which are reported to work, are being blocked by Babel, which throws the same error message as above.

What's the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `async` to your function:

```
 isPreviousPassword: async (v) => {
  var credentials = await firebase.auth().currentUser
    .reauthenticateWithCredential(
        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(
        firebase.auth().currentUser.email, 
        v)
    )

  return credentials || 'Your password is incorrect'
}
```

Comment: Hi Max! I've attempted your recommendation and it hasn't resolved the issue.

Comment: @AlexanderPerchov do you get error on the same line? maybe there is another line where you call `isPreviousPassword` in another function without `async`